# Endless ViewPager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Let's say I have two pages in my viewpager, is it any way to move from page 2 to page 1, but doing this like user is accesing page 3 (with all the animation)

Comment: You mean, these two page should coming with continuously?

Comment: This sample [project](https://github.com/nickwph/InfinitePageView) from github might give you an idea on what you need.

Comment: I don't know if you guys can run this project, but it seems to be crashed on the first time I fling to next page.

Comment: @autobot_101 There might be issues with the current version of android. I haven't been working on android for some time and I believe there should be better implementations now.

Comment: @blessenm Thanks, I have tried it on 2 different devices, one runs Android 2.3.6 and the other runs Android 4.1.2.
Both of them throws exception. And the sad thing is it seems to be no other way to deal with this design :(

Comment: @autobot Whats the exception? Can you give info on your issue in detail in my github issue tracker for the repo. Ill see if I can get it to aleast work on the device.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using a custom FragmentPagerAdapter that provides  the same fragments over and over again:

```
private class EndlessPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private EndlessPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                return fragmentOne;
            } else {
                return fragmentTwo;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }
```

Set the adapter for your ViewPager and start somewhere in the middle to allow almost endless swiping in either direction:

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(new EndlessPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.MAX_VALUE/2);
```